# Find the Matrix $A^{482}$ in terms of $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 3\\ 
-7 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$ Find $A^{482}$ in terms of $A$

I tried using Characteristic equation of $A$ which is $$|\lambda I-A|=0$$ which gives

$$A^2=A-I$$ so $$A^4=A^2A^2=(A-I)^2=A^2-2A+I=-A$$ so

$$A^4=-A$$ but $482$ is neither multiple of $4$ nor Power of $2$, How can I proceed ?

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange Interpolation? You may also want to check how you've used the characteristic equation.

Comment: @IrregularUser "Lagrange Interpolation" ?? Care to explain how this would be relevant?

Comment: @Did I didn't read the question fully apparently, I didn't realise that OP wanted the answer in terms of $A$, nor did I assume that his matrix was nice enough to give some sort of periodicity. If however he wanted $A^n$, for some general $n$ and $A$ not necessarily nice, then Lagrange Interpolation would give your power of a matrix.

Comment: You can calculate the remainder of 482 after division by 4, $A^{482} = A^{120 \cdot 4+2} = {(A^{4})}^{120}A^2$ and then simplifying the first factor and keep going with the same idea.

Comment: @IrregularUser Every matrix is liable to the same treatment as the present one (especially 2x2 matrices). On the other hand, I have no idea of what an approach based on Lagrange interpolation would look like. Care to explain?

Comment: @Did It seems rather laborious to do it this way in general. Let us consider for example, take the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -2 &1 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -2 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 & -2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$. Say we want to compute $A^n$. We can use Lagrange's interpolation polynomial by supposing that $\phi (A) = 0$, for a polynomial $\phi (z)$ (so we can take it to be, for example, the minimal or characteristic polynomial). Division by remainder takes us from $z^n = q(z) \phi (z) + h(z)$ to $A^n = q(A) \phi (A) + h(A) = h(A)$.

Comment: @Did  If we know the roots of $\phi (z)$, say $\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_k$, with their multiplicities $m_1, \ldots, m_k$, then $h(z)$ can be found by solving the system of simulatenous equations in coefficients of $h(z)$ given by $f^{(t)}(\alpha_j) = h^{(t)}(\alpha_j)$, where $f(z) = z^n$ and $f^{(t)}$ is the $t$th derivative. i.e. $h(z)$ is Lagrange's interpolation polynomial for the function $z^n$ at the roots of $\phi (z)$. Can you find $A^n$ using Lagrange's interpolation yourself now?

Comment: @Did Clarification on when I say "It seems rather laborious to do it this way in general" - I'm not refering to the method of Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @IrregularUser It happens that none of this is necessary to solve the case of 2x2 matrices. (And I wonder how what I can or cannot "find myself" is relevant.)

Comment: @Did Of course it isn't "necessary", but the method of Lagrange interpolation generalises to general functions. How would you go about finding $e^{tA}$ for example? I didn't understand what you meant in brackets, but I think you're referring to my comment of "Can you find...$? In which case, you requested what an approach based on Lagrange interpolation would look like and I gave an explanation, but really, it can be found in any undergrad linear algebra course so references shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: @IrregularUser Again? What is or is not in undergrad algebra courses (say, are you trying to be insulting?) is irrelevant, what should be relevant to you should be to avoid sending the OP to unnecessarily complicated roads. (And one can very well compute exponentials of 2x2 matrices with no Lagrange interpolation, of course.)

Comment: @Did What do you mean by "again"? I'm not really sure what you're making my comments out to be - your initial comment was ""Lagrange Interpolation" ?? Care to explain how this would be relevant?", which I believe I have answered, but you seem to claim it isn't relevant at all. Though this is a talk that's suited for meta since it seems to fall under the topic of using methods that may or mat not be outside of the range of OP's knowledge. However, I'm sorry if you feel that I've been insulting (this is not the intention at all - after all, what would be the point?).

Comment: @Did The comment of what is or isn't in undergrad courses is made with the intention of helping you understand how Lagrange interpolation would solve this question. So I'm no really sure why you believe that it is irrelevant since it should answer your initial comment (I really could have just provided a link to some worked examples and we could be done here already).

Comment: @IrregularUser As was pointed at explicitely from the very first comment of this thread, you might want to focus on explaining how Lagrange can be the direction to send the OP to, to solve the present question (2x2 matrix).

Comment: @Did I've already provided an example with a $4 \times 4$ matrix using Lagrange, applying it to the $2 \times 2$ matrix is easier. The method isn't difficult and OP should be able to apply it to their question now.

Comment: @IrregularUser The question asks about a 2x2 matrix, not 4x4. Oh wait, did I mention this already *four* times and does this say something about the way you engage the question in my comment, that I had to? Probably this does.

Comment: @Did I don't understand what the problem is, I've explained the method, explained the obvious relevance of it, and it's applicable to matrces of any size. I've chosen to not answer OP's question directly, which is why I've posted a comment instead. Why? Because I didn't want to type out a full answer. I don't understand why you seem so disatisfied when I've answered all of the queries that you've had regarding it - are there more?

Comment: @IrregularUser Irrespectively of all the satisfecits that you see fit to grant to yourself, you still have not answered the only question I asked. This attitude has a name, which is *stalling*. You have every right to think Lagrange interpolation is cool (it is), but it is misleading to pretend to an unsuspecting OP that it would be the way to go, to solve anything vaguely related to powers of (2x2...) matrices.

Comment: @Did Method of Lagrange interpolation for OP's question: Let $g$ be a polynomial such that $g(A) = 0$, so take the characteristic equation or minimal polynomial. Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree less than the rank of $A$, so take $f = \alpha  x + \beta$. Let $h$ be a function such that $h(A) = A^n$. So take $h(x) = x^n$. Setting up the Lagrange conditions, we see that $g$ has two distinct complex roots. So set up $f(\lambda _1) = h(\lambda _1)$, $f(\lambda _2) = h(\lambda _2)$. Solve for $\alpha$ an $\beta$, write down your $f(A)$ and insert $n = 482$ and we're done.

Comment: @IrregularUser *Et voilà...* As soon as one writes this in detail (but I would love to see you really "insert $n=482$"...), one sees that Lagrange is irrelevant. Compare to the method whose beginning the OP themselves explain in their question.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure what you mean by "satisfecit". The only question that you asked was how Lagrange interpolation was relevant, and I already answered it very early on. From those answers you can easily get to the comment before this one.

Comment: @Did See the third comment of this comment thread.

Comment: @IrregularUser I saw this comment, as the others, and it does not address the question, as the others. Stalling again.

Comment: @Did The question of OP's? Yes, it doesn't which is why I made the third comment. Lagrange interpolation DOES NOT answer OP's question of "how do I proceed?", which again, is already pointed out in the third comment. However, the rest of the comments answer your question of how Lagrange is relevant to powers of matrices. It generalises to larger matrices, and other functions - if you do not see how this is relevant at this point, then giving up on my side is the best thing in my opinion, too much time has already been spent going over the same thing with seemingly little effort on your behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you calculate $A^3$ you get $A^3=-I$ thus now raising both sudes to $160$ we get $A^{480}=I$ so $A^{482}=A^2$ thus $A^2=A-I$

Answer (score 3):

If $A^4=-A$, then $$A^{482}=A^2A^{480}=A^2(A^4)^{120}=A^2(-A)^{120}=A^2(A^4)^{30}=A^2(-A)^{30}=A^{32}=(A^4)^8=(-A)^8=(A^4)^2=(-A)^2=A^2$$

Comment: thanks that is  a good approach